# Force the GIL not to switch threads

Tags: python, multithreading, profiling, gil

I'm profiling some multi-threaded [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) code.
In order to measure the time it takes to execute a specific code segment, I would like to force the [GIL (Global Interpreter Lock)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) to **not** switch between threads for that segment. How can this be done?

**UPDATE:**
Assume the following pseudo-code:

```
some_code_1()
make_the_interpreter_not_change_thread()
take_start_time()   # time critical
code_to_profile()   # time critical
take_end_time()     # time critical
release_the_interpreter()
some_code_2()
```

My concern is that the interpreter will switch thread during the 'time critical' profiling period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GIL doesn't switch threads. The GIL is a mutex that prevents multiple threads from executing bytecode at the same time. As such, to prevent thread switching you need to look elsewhere.

You could call [`sys.setcheckinterval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setcheckinterval) with a really large value to prevent switching while your code is being profiled.

Whenever you call `sys.setcheckinterval(count)` the current 'counter' is reset to the new value, so as soon as you call it no thread switch is allowed for at least `count` bytecode instructions.

Comment: See my question update. Would placing a large number via `sys.setcheckinterval()` in `make_the_interpreter_not_change_thread()` work? Does the interpreter change the current count of python virtual instructions, or would the new value take affect only on the next cycle of the interpreter check, which could unfortunately happen during `code_to_profile()`?

Comment: @Jonathan: The function resets the current count when called. So calling it with a large value guarantees that no thread switch will be made for that number of bytecode instructions.